# Copy contents of one mappings to another

Tags: solidity, evm, mapping

I know this had been answered before but that's with the solc v0.4.x, with v0.8.6 is there any way to copy mappings from one storage variable to another without looping over the mapping index as it will be quite gas heavy operation in my case?

I have 2 mappings -

```
mapping(address => Stake[]) private stakeholderToStake;
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address=> Stake[]) private snapshotsStakes;
```

I want to copy mappings from `stakeholderToStake` to the `snapshotsStakes`. Is there any "gas-friendly" way to do it?

Comment: Copying mappings is a feature that would require support from the EVM. The EVM doesn't have such opcode and it is unlikely it will be implemented since keys are not stored. What's your use case? Perhaps there's an alternative to your problem without copying large amounts of data.

Comment: `snapshotsStakes` is a mapping between counter (which is incremented per month), and we want to take a snapshot of a stakeholder's stake at the end of every month. So, when stakeholder wants to claim their rewards, the function will basically do the rewards calculation based on the snapshot's Stake[] details. So was looking to copy the stakes at the end of the month from `stakeholderToStake` to `snapshotsStakes`

We tried doing the calculation at end of every month but it involves `for` loop which is not much scalable in our case due to the number of stakeholders.

Comment: An usual approach to that type of problems that don't involve taking snapshots is to assign 'shares' to each staker, and rewards are in proportion to the share. For example 100 users with 1 share each, if there are 200 tokens then each share represents 2 tokens. For 10 tokens as reward (5%) then each share represents 2.1 tokens. If someone withdraw its stake it will take 2.1 tokens, there will be 207,9 tokens for the remaining stakers, 2.1 for each. If someone wants to enter it will have to 'buy' shares at 2.1 tokens, for 2 tokens it will receive 0,95 shares approx.

Comment: Hi Ismael, we looked at this and if our understanding was right, a stakeholder can stake, un-stake, stake, un-stake and take advantage of the program. Please have a look at this simple example in excel - https://tinyurl.com/ye5d93np

Comment: The problem with the spreadsheet is that you are mixing shares with tokens. If staker1 stakes 500 tokens with share at 1.05 they will receive 476.19 shares, so they can withdraw 476.19 shares x 1.05 = 500 tokens.

Comment: @Ismael what could be the hedge cases that we should test in this flow? use cases we should test in truffle? please do not hesitate to add your answer below

Comment: @Ismael we saw your eth address on your profile, we can send you some funds if needed.

Comment: @Viktor.w One edge case is when everyone leaves the stake, so no stakers and share price is undefined, others is when one address withdraws its full balance and enters again, or it just leaves a really small amount. There's no need to send anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a friendly way

```
mapping(address => Stake[]) private stakeholderToStake;
mapping(uint256 => address) private snapshotsStakes;
```

`uint256 => address => Stake[]`

Then you can use `stakeholderToStake[snapshotsStakes[x]]` to access the elements of `stakeholderToStake` by uint256 x.

Comment: `stakeholderToStake` will keep on updating and we want to take a snapshot of stake details at the end of every month and perform the calculation based on it.

Comment: You can use a counter, each time a new stakeholder is created assign the current counter value to address and increment it by one. At the end of the month, you can use a for loop to get each stakeHolder.

Comment: The `for` loop is what we are trying to avoid. We did some basic benchmarks and found out that a loop of around 2000 stakeholders with simple addition is in danger to go out of gas.

Comment: You can do the loop off-chain by using a view function to get stakeHolder data. It will still cost gas to write 2000 "stakeHolder" data on the chain after the loop.